# Swift init method from JSONJoy protocol not available as Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, init

I'm having an issue with getting the Objective-C selector for a Swift init method that is required to be implemented by the JSONJoy protocol.  The reason I want to be able to get the selector for the init method is so that I can instantiate the Swift class programatically based on the class name which doesn't seem possible in the Swift API's so need to go down to Objective-C to do it.  I am using the routine at https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/1613121 to print out all of the methods for each class and their parent classes and the selector is always showing up as "init", but from my understanding it should be showing up as "init:" because it has a parameter.

The JSONJoy protocol is:

```
public protocol JSONJoy {
    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder)
}
```

To test, I tried creating my own protocol named "TestProtocol".  Below are my results.

`init(str: String) {}` shows up with a selector of "initWithStr:"

`required public init(str: String) {}` still shows up with a selector of **"initWithStr:"**

Taking away the protocol and just implementing the methods directly in my class using a method signature **"init(str: String)"**, it still shows up as **"initWithStr:".**

All the above tests with and without the "TestProtocol" are generating selectors as expected.

However, no matter how I manipulate the JSONJoy protocol signature it always shows up as plain **"init"** without any parameters when I list the selectors for the class.  I tried removing the "_" and adding additional parameters to the protocol, however it still comes out as "init"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a Swift protocol available in Objective-C you need to add the `@objc` attribute to the protocol declaration.

You can test the Objective-C method signature by using `respondsToSelector()`, as in the following Playground example:

```
@objc protocol Foo 
{
    init(_ someNumber: Int)
}

@objc(MYBar) class Bar : NSObject, Foo 
{
    required init(_ someNumber: Int) 
    {
        println("Got \(someNumber)")
    }
}

var bar = Bar(123)
bar.respondsToSelector("init:") // true
NSClassFromString("MYBar")?.alloc() // `Bar` instance
```

Comment: This was the solution to get the init method to show up as `initWithDecoder:`.  Thanks!  However, I'm still stumped as to why I could create a Swift protocol that did not have the @objc annotation that had a signature of `init(_ str: String)` and it would show up as `initWithStr:` whereas `init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder)` would not show up as `initWithDecoder:` unless I put the @objc annotation.

Answer (score 0):

An initializer with a first parameter with an external parameter name of `foo` (i.e. `init(foo bar:Int)`), will by default become `initWithFoo:` in Objective-C. When you do not explicitly specify an external name for an initializer parameter, the external name will be implicitly made to be the same as the internal name. So when you write `init(str: String)`, it is implicitly `init(str str: String)`, you have to use it like `MyClass(str: something)`, and the Objective-C selector is `initWithStr:`.

You can always explicitly suppress the external name by using `_` where you would specify the external name. This is what they do with the first parameter of the initializer in `JSONJoy` (`init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder)`). You can do the same thing:

```
init(_ str: String)
```

and then you would use it like `MyClass(something)`, and the Objective-C selector would be `init:`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the fact that it should have showed up as `initWithDecoder:`, however it was not showing up with that selector until I put the @objc annotations on the JSONJoy protocol.  As I mentioned before, I'm still stumped as to why I could create another Swift protocol that doesn't have the @objc tag and the generation of the init selector worked correctly.

Comment: @kglee79: No, it should NOT have showed up as `initWithDecoder:`, because it had no external parameter name. It should have showed up a `init:` the way it was declared. You do not need `@objc` annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not showing up as `init:` either.  Unless I put the `@objc` annotation on it, it would only show up as `init`.